# Python: How to find a letter in a sentence's list of words and return those words in their original case (upper/lower)

Tags: python, list, case

I'm trying to create a Python function that takes a sentence, turns it into a list, and determines whether a given letter appears in any word in that list, regardless of letter case.  I would like the function then to return just a list of those words that have that letter, with each word’s letters in their original cases.

I have been able to return those words, but all letters are now in lower case, even if they were originally upper case.  How do I return the words with their letters in their original cases?

What I’ve written:

```
def word_with(word, char):
    char_lower = char.lower()
    word_lower = word.lower()
    word_string = word_lower.split()
    word_with = [x for x in word_string if char_lower in x]
    return word_with
```

When I test with:

> word = "She sells seashells by the seashore"
>   print(word_with(word, "s"))

The output is:

> ['she', 'sells', 'seashells', 'seashore']

but I want the 'she' to have a capital ’S' as it appears in the original.  How do I do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours isn't working because you're making the word lowercase before checking. Do it while checking to see if it's in the word, as so:

```py
def word_with(sent, letter):
    x = [word for word in sent.split() if letter in word.lower()]
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move your `.lower()` call into the conditional part of your list comprehension, you can return the original word.

Something like this:

```py
    def words_with(s, char):
        char_lower = char.lower()
        # Get individual words
        words = s.split()
        # Return all words that contain char
        return [word for word in words if char_lower in word.lower()]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
[x for x in word_string if char_lower in x.lower()]
```

---

```
def word_with(word, char):
    char_lower = char.lower()
    word_string = word.split()
    word_with = [x for x in word_string if char_lower in x.lower()]
    return(word_with)


word = "She sells seashells by the seashore"
print(word_with(word, "s"))
```

---

```
['She', 'sells', 'seashells', 'seashore']
```

Comment: he doesn't want to capitalize each match... he only wants the original word as it was represented in the original unmodified input.

Answer (score 0):

Don't perform any casting on the string, and use regex in your generator instead of the `in` keyword:

```
def word_with(word, char):
    return [x for x in word.split() if re.search(char, x, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't have experience with regex yet.  I put "import re" on the first line and your suggestion worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try splitting before going to lowercase and returning those words based on the index you get from you list comprehension.

```py
def word_with(word, char):
    char_lower = char.lower()<br/>
    original_split = word.split()
    word_lower = word.lower()<br/>
    word_string = word_lower.split()<br/>
    word_with = [x for x in range(len(word_string)) if char_lower in word_string[i]]<br/>
    return([original_split[i] for i in word_with])
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do this using regex:
pls check if you had got the desired output with this code

```
import re
def word_with(word, char):
    word_string = word.split()
    print(word_string)
    word_with = [x for x in word_string if re.search(r'^[s]',x,re.I)]
    return(word_with)

word = "She sells seashells by the seashore"
print(word_with(word,'s'))
```

Comment: Thank you.  I subtracted the line "print(word_string)" and it gave me the output I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That will return you the original word from the letter that match the char

```
def word_with(word, char):
    return [x for x in word.split() if char.lower() in x.lower()]
```